# SSH key access won't work after tinkering with Samba on server

Tags: ssh, samba, ssh-keys

I spent some time logged into a server ([Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian)) trying to get [Samba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28software%29) access to work better from my Mac.

After logging out and attempting to log back in I was unable to log in using my private key which has been working for years.

Private key login worked for another user from the same client machine, and I was able to modify the sshd.config to allow password login so that I could log back onto the server.

What could I have done to break the keyed login just for my username and why?

I was messing around with creating a Samba password for my username, and I also made my home folder 777 to try to get write access working from Samba. (This was NOT a recursive [chmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) so the folders below are not 777.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your home directory should never be ugo+rwx (777).  You should not allow other users to write to your home directory.  The ssh daemon checks for file system permissions and will refuse to use the contents of ~/.ssh/ if it or its parent (~/) is writable by other users.

See http://www.openssh.org/faq.html question # 3.14.

Also see 'man sshd_config' and StrictModes (don't turn it off).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sounds like it is the permissions on the parent (ie my home folder on the server that is the problem). I guess I was getting desparately frustrated with samba always giving permission errors!

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on logging in your sshd config if it isn't already. That'll tell you exactly what went wrong. It's often a permission problem on the files in ~/.ssh

The logfile is usually in either /var/log/secure or /var/log/auth.log

Comment: I'll check that more carefully. But normally I thought it was just the permissions on the private key end rather than the public key end?

Comment: Giving others the ability to write to your authorized_keys file (for example) would let them login as you. SSH won't let you login with a key if others can write to your .ssh folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is another possibility that none of the earlier answers have raised: [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux). If this is active, it will prevent the .ssh folder from being accessed via a Samba share.

It is easy to test: temporarily disable SELinux ("setenforce 0") and see if the .ssh folder can be accessed.